# How do I read a deployed file in MAUI/Xamarin on Android

Tags: android, .net-core, xamarin.forms, maui

I have a small MAUI app i'm testing with. Im trying to read a file that was part of the deployment. I have the code below, which works great in a Windows deploy of the MAUI app, but crashes in Android. What is the proper cross-platform way to do this?

```
        // TODO get from service or xml
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        //var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        var fullpath = Path.Combine(path, "Services\\questions.json");
        var json = File.ReadAllText(fullpath);
```

Comment: you need to be more specific about what "part of the deployment" means.  Was it an Android Asset?  An embedded resource?  A content file?  In any scenario, I don't think "path\\file" is a valid Android path.  If a file is included as Content, you should be able to read if using a relative path from the Android app roof (ie, "Services/questions.json")

Comment: A text file with copy always set to true

Comment: what is the Build Action of the file?

Comment: It was none.  Im going to try it as Maui Asset per the answer below

Answer (score 8):

MAUI has a new way to access files included with the app: `MauiAsset`.

**UPDATE**: More detail in [Resource Files section of Maui doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/single-project#resource-files).

Early description in blog [Announcing .NET MAUI Preview 4, Raw Assets](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-maui-preview-4/#raw-assets):

> .NET MAUI now makes it very easy to add other assets to your project and reference them directly while retaining platform-native performance. For example, if you want to display a static HTML file in a WebView you can add the file to your project and annotate it as a MauiAsset in the properties.

```
<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\index.html" />
```

> Tip: you can also use wildcards to enable all files in a directory:

```
... Include="Resources\Raw\*" ...
```

> Then you can use it in your application by filename.

```
<WebView Source="index.html" />
```

---

`MauiAssetPage.xaml`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTests.MauiAssetPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <!-- By the time Maui is released, this is all you will need. -->
        <!-- The Init code-behind won't be needed. -->
        <WebView x:Name="MyWebView" Source="TestWeb.html" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

`MauiAssetPage.xaml.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MauiTests
{
    public partial class MauiAssetPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MauiAssetPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // *** Hopefully this block of code no longer needed for WebView Source. ***
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await InitAsync();
            });
        }


        // *** Hopefully this is no longer needed. ***
        private async Task InitAsync()
        {
            string filePath = "TestWeb.html";
            var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath);

            if (stream != null)
            {
                string s = (new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd();
                this.MyWebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = s };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`TestWeb.html`:

```
(whatever html you want)
```

In `Solution Explorer`, add `TestWeb.html` to your project. In its `Properties`, select `Build Action` = `MauiAsset`.

Comment: hrm, this makes sense, but the conditional defines don't seem to be defined for me, or working correctly. When I set my debug target to "Windows Machine" it doesn't use the Windows path.

Comment: Added update to show the fix.

Comment: Does it still work the same? I tried but when I call `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` I get a `FileNotFound` exception (which wraps a `Java.IO.IOFileNotFoundException`, running from Android emulator).
The file was automatically set as MauiAsset and I'm specifically including the file in the project.

Comment: @IIARROWS - not sure what is going on for you - please create a new question tagged maui, and show more details about what you did.

Comment: I found the solution... I had to include in the path "Resources/Raw/". I got to this after watching the sample solution, seeing that the file are in the root folder.

Comment: This is not "very easy". I think they should change their documentation to say: ".NET MAUI now makes it VERY HARD to add other assets to your project"

Comment: ..also this answer needs an update since Microsoft.Maui.Essentials is no longer a thing.

Comment: Corrected to match current Maui version. **I think all the comments above no longer apply;** `MauiAsset` build action should "just work", with files in **shared "Resources" folder** - no longer need to put them in per-platform folder, nor adjust file path per platform, unless need a resource to be different on each platform.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I do need them to be different on each platform. How to do this now, for Maui, doesn't seem to be documented any where. Should they be a MauiAsset in this case? Or an AndroidAsset?

Answer (score 0):

I tried looking for a solution to this for months. I ended up hosting the file online then creating a method to download the file during runtime

```
public  async Task DownloadFile(string fileName)
{  
          if (File.Exists(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory + $"/{fileName}"))
            {
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                try
                {
                    
                    NetworkAccess networkAccess = Connectivity.Current.NetworkAccess;

                    if (networkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
                    {
                        
                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            var uri = new Uri($"https://myhostedfile.com/{fileName}");
                            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCallback2);//checking if download is complete
                            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(MaintainProgress);//event handler to check download progress
                            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory + $"/{fileName}");
                            
                        });

                    }

                    else
                        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("No Internet", "Failed to get some files from the internet, confirm if your internet is" +
                          "working", "OK");



                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "Failed to get some files from the internet, confirm if your internet is" +
                        "working", "OK");
                }
            }          
        }
```

Then you can access your file URL using:

```
string filePath = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory + $"/myfile.pdf;
```

Comment: Hosting the file online maybe it's not always the solution. The question was about linking a local file.

Comment: Once you download the file, it will become local then you link it. Do you have a better answer? Coz it seems like there was no solution available for a long time.

Comment: Did you encounter a problem with the answer I wrote in 2021? Granted it was out of date, but I assumed people could figure out the small changes needed, by looking at Maui docs. Anyway, I've updated it to match current Maui version.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for load values from Json File for .NET MAUI ANDROID,
I Have Country Codes in my json file like

```
[
{
    "countryName": "Afghanistan",
    "code": "AF",
    "phoneCode": "93"
},
{
    "countryName": "Ã…land Islands",
    "code": "AX",
    "phoneCode": "358"
},
{
    "countryName": "Albania",
    "code": "AL",
    "phoneCode": "355"
},
{
    "countryName": "Algeria",
    "code": "DZ",
    "phoneCode": "213"
},
```

and I pasted this json file in my Project(not in specific folder) and
set that's Build Action to "MauiAsset"

then I created object for this json values like

```
  public class CountryDetails
  {
    public string countryName { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string phoneCode { get; set; }
  }
```

and finally this is the medhod to get values and load in one list from json file

```
 public async Task LoadCountries()
    {
        try
        {
            List<CountryDetails> countries = new List<CountryDetails>();
            string filePath = "countries.json";
            var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath);

            if (stream != null)
            {
                string s = (new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd();
                countries=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CountryDetails>>(s);
            }
            if (countries != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in countries)
                {
                    CountryDetails.Add(item);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            string exe = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Happy Coding!!!