# How to Expand BlazorWebView to the phone size without specifying hard coded values in MAUI app

Tags: blazor, maui, .net-maui

MAUI doesn't accept values like "auto" or "*" so I am kind of stuck how to make the webview expand to the all phone screen area.

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui;assembly=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleAPP;"
             x:Class="SampleAPP.Index"   >
    <Grid   height   >
        <b:BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html"      >
            <b:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <b:RootComponent Selector="app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:MainComponent}" />
            </b:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </b:BlazorWebView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

here is how it is look like :
[image]

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Take away the Grid

Comment: I did , nothing changed @MisterMagoo

Comment: What exactly is the symptom? Is there content that is cut off, or is it that the page background color or image doesn't fill the screen?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have added the image, I think MAUI is not ready for development, few documentation , almost no question answered on stackoverflow , same thing I was able to do it in Xamarin in 5 minutes . However I was prefering MAUI since it is single project for all of the platforms

Comment: Hmm. That is surprisingly bad result - a number of people have been trying out Maui Blazor - haven't seen anything that extreme happen. (I haven't tested it myself, except to run an existing sample. Which had a white background, and not much content, so didn't test whether filled screen or not.) What does the HTML contain? If you make a public repo at github, with minimum code needed to show the problem, someone will probably see that link here, take a look at it.

Comment: You could continue to use regular `WebView` as in X-Forms. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442740/199364) that uses "MauiAsset" build action for the assets. But it would be good to see a repo using Blazor, to show the issue you encountered.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve the white screen showed to me when I didn't use local file , try to set it to index.html to work fine not to remote website, as for WebView I ll try as all what I want a WebView functionality , will try to upload the app to some public repo once I get a chance .

Comment: Did you create your project BEFORE the current preview version of VS? (VS 2022 Preview, 17.1.0 Preview 4.0). If so, I would create a new project, from current `Maui Blazor App (Preview)` Template. See if that works better as-is. Then adapt it with your code.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I used 17.1 version to create new project , however I stiched the sdk to blazer from project file manually as it was originally MAUI app sdk

Comment: Yeah, that's not good enough, imho. Use `Maui **Blazor** App (Preview)` template. See the files that generates. And make sure you have updated to latest VS - Preview 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding ColumnDefinitions="*" RowDefinitions="*" for the grid

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui;assembly=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleAPP;"
             x:Class="SampleAPP.Index"   >
    <Grid  ColumnDefinitions="*"
        RowDefinitions="*"  >
        <b:BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html"      >
            <b:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <b:RootComponent Selector="app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:MainComponent}" />
            </b:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </b:BlazorWebView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Didn't work  I event tried to set them manually like this : 
private void Index_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         HeightRequest = blazorWebView.HeightRequest = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
        WidthRequest = blazorWebView.WidthRequest = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;


    }

Comment: what is u replace grid by stack?

Comment: I tried Stack and both oerientations , nothing change the BlazorWebView unless I hard code the height and width