# How do I connect my MAUI app to a Firestore database? (via service account json file)

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, maui

Creating a MAUI app and trying to connect it to the Firestore. I'm following [the advice here](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest) to download a service account JSON file and set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

I downloaded my service file from my firebase project online, renamed it to `GoogleAppCredentials.json`, and then included it in my MAUI project [with the Build Action "MauiAsset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70442638/how-do-i-read-a-deployed-file-in-maui-xamarin-on-android) like so:

[image: GoogleAppCredentials location]

My cs file then references the file:

```
string path = "GoogleAppCredentials.json";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);
```

But when I run the app on Android Emulator I get the following error:

```
System.AggregateException
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (Error reading credential file from location GoogleAppCredentials.json: Could not find file '/GoogleAppCredentials.json'.
Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
```

And on Windows Machine...

```
System.AggregateException
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (Error reading credential file from location GoogleAppCredentials.json: Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\GoogleAppCredentials.json'.
Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
```

So with MAUI, how do I properly copy `GoogleAppCredentials.json` into the app (if not MauiAsset, what else?) and then reference it in the `.cs` file?

Comment: Any news?  Did you find a solution? I Have the same problem..

Answer (score 2):

> Creating a MAUI app and trying to connect it to the Firestore. I'm following [the advice here](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest) to download a service account JSON file and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.

This .NET Client is for backend services. You can install it and it can start to run, but they are designed to be used in .net services in the Google Cloud environment.

MAUI is a Multi-targeted project which adds the ability to hold all codebase in the project insted of adding a separate project per platform as it is in Xamarin. The multi-target project steal is built to specific platform artifacts with platform binding. For example, `net6.0-android` included android bindings with all standard Android ecosystems.

To integrate with Firebase Firestore you need to use Android guidelines and libraries: Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore and configure google-services.json with GoogleServicesJson build action, but in MAUI you need to do this in the Platform/Andoroid location.

My csproj contains this configurations

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Platforms\Android\google-services.json" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <GoogleServicesJson Include="Platforms\Android\google-services.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For my project, I do not target WinUI so I using this Lib for accessing Firestore [Plugin.CloudFirestore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CloudFirestore/)

Comment: Can you go into more detail about this? You say to use Platform/Android location. What exactly do we put there, though? What about if we want to use it on iOS?

Comment: @AdamB in Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin Traditional you need to create separate Project for each platform: **MyApp.Android**, **MyApp.iOS**. And they simple represented all platform specific code. This is simpler for understanding. In MAUI you now have on project with Platform folder which dynamically link on build for specific target. So for configuring such things simply use same instructions that you find for Product that you what integrate, but instead of **MyApp.Android** project you use **Platform/Android** for **MyApp.iOS** use **Platform/iOS**. And search for Xamarin.** packages.

Comment: Where do you call Firebase,InitializeApp(context)? Tried in mainactivity, but that did not work

Comment: @OneBigQuestion Actually I did not call this explicitly as I used [Plugin.CloudFirestore](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore) For Android it not requires this actions.