# How do I connect my MAUI app to a Firestore database in production?

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, maui

I'm creating a MAUI app and I'm trying to connect it to Firestore.
I have set everything up in Firebase and I can successfully connect to the Firestore by setting the environment variable: "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" on my windows machine locally.

However, I cannot make it work if I test out the app using my local android device since this device doesn't have the environment variable set up.

So my question is, how would I go about doing this, so I can connect to the Firestore on my android device?

Some thoughts:

1. I would imagine that I need to set the environment variable in the MAUI code and somehow read it, but wouldn't that expose the secret file since it would now exist inside the MAUI project?
2. It looks like some people are using the google-services.json file for this purpose (which is not strictly secret) so if I could use that instead, then I guess that would be the best, but again, how would I do that?
3. I have tried adding the files in the Asset files, .csproj file, setting environment variables in the MainProgram etc. but I just can't make it work and even worse, I'm unsure whether that approach would be insecure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Possible duplicate: [How do I connect my MAUI app to a Firestore database? (via service account json file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877262/how-do-i-connect-my-maui-app-to-a-firestore-database-via-service-account-json)

I just still don't understand how they made it work.

Comment: I have checked the link you provided and found that the package Plugin.CloudFireStore not support .net 6.0. In addrion, according to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1346), it seems an existed issue.

Comment: That seems weird since I can actually use this library to make queries to the database, I just can't figure out where to store the secrets so that I can make this work when testing it out on mobile phones

Comment: You can try to put it in the Platform\Android folder just like the answer in the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

*This is how I successfully set it up in .NET Maui:*

1. Copy the "Json" file from Google under the "Resource/Raw" folder
   with  a BuildAction "MauiAsset"
2. Below is my initialization code:

```
        public async Task<FirestoreDb> initFirestore()
        {
            try
            {
                var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(Constants.FirestoreKeyFilename);
                var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

                FirestoreClientBuilder fbc = new FirestoreClientBuilder { JsonCredentials = contents };
                return FirestoreDb.Create(Constants.FirestoreProjectID, fbc.Build());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps.