# MAUI - Android - How to read asset files?

Tags: android, maui, android-assets

I am developing a MAUI project with VS2022.
My issue comes with this snipped where I try to read two files from disk and use them as parameters for another function.

```
CopyFileToAppDataDirectory("vocab.json");
CopyFileToAppDataDirectory("merges.json");
var tokenizer = new Tokenizer(new Bpe(GetAssetFilePath("vocab.json"), GetAssetFilePath("merges.txt")));
```

Both files are part of the project, I copied them in a folder called Assets inside the Android folder.
[image]

The function Bpe throws an exception indicating that the file does not exist in the location.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file '/data/user/0/com.companyname.familytunesv3/files/vocab.json'.'

Both files have the build action set to "**EmbeddedResource**" and "**Copy Always**"
[image]

the code of the auxiliary functions

```
public async Task CopyFileToAppDataDirectory(string filename)
{
// Open the source file
using Stream inputStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filename);
    
// Create an output filename
string pathfile = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory + "/files/";
string targetFile = Path.Combine(pathfile, filename);
    
// Copy the file to the AppDataDirectory
using FileStream outputStream = File.Create(targetFile);
await inputStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
}


string GetAssetFilePath(string assetFileName)
{
var assetPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory,assetFileName);
return assetPath;
}
```

any idea how to make it work?

thanks a lot.

Comment: you read Android Assets with AssetManager.  If you want to do this in a cross-platform way, use embedded resources instead of Assets

Comment: @Jason, I would prefer to do this in a cross-platform way, I used a function I just found in microsoft doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=windows   still the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by setting the build action to "MauiAsset" and using the function

```
public async Task CopyFileToAppDataDirectory(string filename)
{
    // Open the source file
    using Stream inputStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filename);

    // Create an output filename
    string targetFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, filename);

    // Copy the file to the AppDataDirectory
    using FileStream outputStream = File.Create(targetFile);
    await inputStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
}
```

the final code was like this

```
 await CopyFileToAppDataDirectory("vocab.json");
 await CopyFileToAppDataDirectory("merges.txt");
  
 var tokenizer = new Tokenizer(new Bpe(GetAssetFilePath("vocab.json"), GetAssetFilePath("merges.txt")));
```

Comment: [MauiAsset use described in an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442740/199364). [Resource files section of Maui doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/single-project#resource-files).